# How to split into lines with pattern

Tags: regex, string, groovy

learning groovy. hope someone can help

How I can split this

```
def lol = "lol1 testline lol2 testline lol3 testline"
```

so that it shows output :

> testline
>   testline
>   testline

I have tried numerous things, most recent

```
def pattern = /([a-z]3)([0-9]1)/
def test = lol.tokenize(pattern)
println(lol.matches(pattern))
test.each {
  println it
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you wanted to repeat *3 letters* and *1 digit*:

```
/[a-z]{3}\d/
```

Also note that `tokenize` doesn't take regexes as delimiter, so you should use `split` instead.